# Public filing of investment fund portfolios - US Funds

Tags: united-states, investing, etf, mutual-funds, portfolio

I follow several investment funds. For some European ones, I can go to the public authority and see their quarterly filings with a detailed composition of the portfolio.

For the US, where could I find their public filings detailing their portfolio? Say for instance the portfolio of Hayden Capital as for their latest filing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're should search [SEC's Edgar database](https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcurrent) for the fund's quarterly 13-F filings. This requirement is for funds managing $100 million or more, so if the fund you're searching for currently manages less, there might be no information.

You can find more details/requirements of 13-F filings [here](https://www.sec.gov/fast-answers/answers-form13fhtm.html).